# Function to add line break without using <br> html

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm currently learning Vue JS and I made a simple app that pulls information from API and displays facts about a country given a 2-letter country code. The data retrieved from API is mapped into `country` and `properties`. It stores details about a country such as timezone, currency, population etc. But some of this information are missing for some countries. I've been trying to make the UI show newline whenever one of the information is missing.

Here, items in `country` and `properties` dictionary is an empty string if the data fetched is null or if its an empty array.

```
          this.country.name = countryName == null ? "" : countryName;
          this.country.capital = capital == null ? "" : capital;
          this.country.currency = currency == null ? "" : currency;
          this.country.phone = phone == null ? "" : phone;
          this.country.emoji = emoji == null ? "" : emoji;
          this.country.languages = languages.length == 0 ? "" : languages;
          this.country.continent = continent == null ? "" : continent;

          this.properties.demonym = demonym == null ? "" : demonym;
          this.properties.area = area == null ? "" : area;
          this.properties.timezones = timezones.length == 0 ? "" : timezones;
          this.properties.population = population == null ? "" : population;
```

In the methods, I have a function that returns `<br>` if any value of `country` or `properties` is equal to an empty string to display a newline on screen.

```
convertToLineBreak(txt) {
  if (!txt) {
    return txt.replace(txt, "<br>");
  }
  return txt;
}
```

This is how it is shown in the UI which is not how I want it to be.

[image]

This is my [app.vue](https://gitlab.com/s-tandun/vue-country/-/blob/main/src/App.vue#L301). I'm mainly concerned about the issue above and I'm also looking for feedback on how to improve the code. I'd appreciate any feedback. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fetching the data from API, it's better to map it into your proper structure (a JavaScript Object). So you can have control on the emptiness of details (properties) or transforming the data for other purposes.

For example:

```
"item": {
 "firstItem": "currency",
 "secondItem" : "timeZone"
 ...
}


const item = {currency: item.firstItem, timeZone: item.secondItem, ...}
```